# How to send complex object over IPC in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using `ipcRenderer.send()` to send an array of objects back to `ipcMain`. Here's my code:

```js
const loadData = async () => {
    let promises = [];
    ['stocks', 'crypto', 'vehicles', 'property'].forEach(item => {
        promises.push(getTableData(item))
    })
    let data = {}
    await Promise.allSettled(promises).then(results => {
        for (let i in results) {
            var result = results[i]
            if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
                console.log(result.value.type)
                // result.value.data will be an array of objects
                console.log(result.value.data)
                data[result.value.type] = result.value.data
            } else {
                console.error(result)
            }
        }
    }).finally(_ => {
        console.log(data)
        ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', data)
    })
}
```

When `result.value.data` is printed via `console.log`, it shows the correct data (comes from an SQL query):

```
{ stocks: [{id: 1, ticker: "BRK.B", action: "ADD", price: 173.97, shares: 6}, ...], ...}
```

However, when it gets printed in `ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', ...)`, it prints empty arrays for the values:

```
{ stocks: [], crypto: [], vehicles: [], property: [] }
```

How would I send an IPC message with a complex object? Is it not being serialized correctly?

---

*For reference,* here is my `ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', ...)` code:

```js
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

*In addition,* here is `getTableData()`:

```js
const getTableData = (table) => {
    let toReturn = {
        type: `${table}`,
        data: []
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            db.run(`PRAGMA table_info('${table}');`, err => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    db.each(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, row) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                        } else {
                            toReturn.data.push(row)
                        }
                    })
                    resolve(toReturn)
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Where each row is an object that looks like:

```
{id: 1, ticker: "AAPL", action: "ADD", price: 100.0,
shares: 10, datetime: "2020-05-14 23:24:50", platform: ""}
```

Comment: it should work - can you confirm console log is not evaluated just now - log json.stringify . Also forEach & push sounds like map ^^

Comment: @Estradiaz Ah, `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` in `ipcRenderer.send(...)` actually produces empty results: `{"stocks":[],"crypto":[],"vehicles":[],"property":[]}`...How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: getTableData? What do you use? Maybe those results have getters that arent accessed in toString - dont expect it to assign the data post fulfilled.

Comment: @Estradiaz I added `getTableData`. If I `console.log(JSON.stringify(row))` within `getTableData`, it turns out as expected, but not in `loadData`

Comment: db.each async? If it is you resolve before you are finished

Comment: @Estradiaz You were correct. I solved this by changing `db.each()` to `db.all()` and resolving the promise in `db.all()`. I got to this solution because of your help - if you can formulate an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Estradiaz's help, I realized that the promise was being resolved before the SQL query had been processed. To fix this, I switched from using `db.each()` to `db.all()`. Here is my updated `getTableData()`:

```js
const getTableData = (table) => {
    let toReturn = {
        type: `${table}`,
        data: []
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            DB.run(`PRAGMA table_info('${table}');`, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    DB.all(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, rows) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err)
                            reject(err)
                        } else {
                            toReturn.data = rows
                            resolve(toReturn)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```